# Calculating Simple Interest and output into tabular form

Tags: qbasic

I'm trying to write a QBASIC Code that allow a user to input **Principal** and **Time** of 5 Investors to Calculates the ***Simple Interest*** of those **5 Investors** and **Output** their, 
**Amount Accrued**, **Principal** and **Time/Duration** in a **Tabular form.** All with an Interest Rate of 12%

I try:

```
DIM P AS DOUBLE
DIM r AS DOUBLE
DIM t AS DOUBLE
DIM A AS DOUBLE
DIM rt AS DOUBLE
CLS
DIM x AS INTEGER
CLS
WHILE x <> 5
    INPUT "Enter First Investor's Principal: ", P
    INPUT "Enter First Investor's Time: ", t
    x = x + 1

WEND
r = 0.12
rt = 1 + (r * t)
A = P * rt
FOR i = 1 TO x
    PRINT "Amount Accrued", "Principal Amount", "Time"
    PRINT
    PRINT A, , P, , t
NEXT i
```

But it keep printing the **last** result 5 times in 5 different tables

I'm Expecting results like below:

```
Amount Accrued    Principal   Time/Duration
44,400            30,000      4
68,000            50,000      3
95,200            70,000      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're overwriting `P` and `t` in every iteration of your `WHILE` loop. Initialise `P` and `t` and other subsequent variables as arrays instead and store different values at different indices of them. Also note that you're always printing **`First`**`Investor's Principal and Time` in each iteration. The investor number should iterate as well. I have fixed the problems in the code below:

```
CLS
DIM x AS INTEGER
INPUT "Number of Investors: ", x
DIM P(x - 1) AS DOUBLE
DIM r AS DOUBLE
DIM t(x - 1) AS DOUBLE
DIM A(x - 1) AS DOUBLE
DIM rt(x - 1) AS DOUBLE

FOR i = 0 TO x - 1
    PRINT "Enter Investor-" + STR$(i + 1) + "'s Principal: "
    INPUT "", P(i)
    PRINT "Enter Investor-" + STR$(i + 1) + "'s Time: "
    INPUT "", t(i)
NEXT i

PRINT "Amount Accrued", "Principal Amount", "Time"
PRINT

r = .12
FOR i = 0 TO x - 1
    rt(i) = 1 + (r * t(i))
    A(i) = (P(i) * rt(i))
    PRINT A(i), P(i), , t(i)
NEXT i
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I needed it but I don't understand the **x - 1** throughout your code, can you please explain it to me.

Comment: The indexing is starting from 0. So let's say if you want to store 3 elements (investors' details), you will store them at 0,1,2 indices; not  at 1,2,3. However, you can have indexing start from 1 as well but then you will have to define `P` as `DIM P(1 TO x) AS DOUBLE` and similarly it goes for other variables.

Comment: BASIC does not require arrays to start at 0 :->

Comment: @eoredson Which is what I have also mentioned in comment above

Comment: That's because it is a 'C' thingy -- they always start at 0 when they dim [10] they only get [0] to [9], not [10] which I have never understood.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler sample of coding for accrued interest:

Note: Arrays default to 10 items without needing DIM, and variables default to single..

```
FOR i = 1 TO 5
    PRINT "Enter Investor-" + STR$(i) + "'s Principal";: INPUT p(i)
    PRINT "Enter Investor-" + STR$(i) + "'s Time";: INPUT t(i)
NEXT
PRINT "Amounts:"
PRINT "Accrued", "Principal", "Time"
PRINT "-------", "---------", "----"
r = .12
FOR i = 1 TO 5
    rt(i) = 1 + (r * t(i))
    a(i) = (p(i) * rt(i))
    PRINT a(i), p(i), t(i)
NEXT
END
```